# C++/VisualStudio2017 : Override c4700 compiling error

Tags: c++

I'm working on a c++ project for the university and I get problems with an uninitialized pointer in the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct t_coord {
    double valeur;
    int indice;
    t_coord *suiv;
};

struct t_vecteur {
    int dimension;
    double defaut;
    t_coord *tete;
};

void initialiser (t_vecteur tv, int dimension, double defaut) {
    tv.dimension = dimension;
    tv.defaut = defaut;
    tv.tete = nullptr;
}

int main () {
    t_vecteur tv;
    initialiser(tv, 5, 3.14);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway to override c4700 error in VisualStudio so I can use my initialization function "initialiser()" ? The final compilation will be done on GNU which does not take in account uninitialized variables and it is specified in the project that I have to create a function to initialize my t_vecteur.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please copy-paste the entire error message. We don't, typically, memorize error codes. EDIT: `struc t_coord` is not a valid C++, and you need semicolon after the type definition.

Comment: A constructor is a function. Its task is to initialize. Why not use a constructor.

Comment: May as well copy the *real* code while you're at it. This stands no chance of compiling, and that has nothing to do with the error your reporting.

Comment: error c4700 : uninitialized local variable 'tv' used

Comment: Because we're not yet working on objects so I have to do the code this way as awkward as it is...

Comment: It's not about 'way of coding'. The code you're showing us still has typos, as if you manually copied it from somewhere. Please copy-paste the exact code that gives you the error.

Comment: Someone actually gave me the solution why it didn't work : I had just forgot a & to let the parameter t_vecteur being modified in the function initialiser()

Comment: @bla1r0: So, why did you want to "override" a perfectly legitimate compiler diagnostic message instead of fixing the actual error in your code?

Comment: @AnT because I thought VisualStudio was not understanding that my t_vecteur was actually initialized in the function just below the declaration which would have been understandable since the initialization is done in quiet a weird way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct `t_vecteur` is an [aggregate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes#Aggregate_classes), and as such the instance `tv` is not initialized (`dimension`, `defaut` and `tete`, being primitive data types, contain indeterminate data).

Then you pass it *by-value* to the function `initialiser`, which *reads* from `tv` when making a copy, which invokes undefined behavior.

The relevant phrase of the standard is in [[dcl.init]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#12):

> When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>
> If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined

To fix it (and the C4700 uninitialized variable warning), pass `tv` to `initialiser`  *by-reference*.

```
void initialiser (t_vecteur& tv, int dimension, double defaut) {
```

Passing by-reference is not reading from `tv`, hence doing so is not UB anymore.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. No need to override c4700 in anyway then ;D !
Thanks for your clear answer !